# Unity How to change notifications badge number on IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, push-notification

I want to change my application notifications badge on Unity IOS.

how to change the little number next to my application on IOS when using unity?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [unity mobile notifications package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.notifications@2.0/manual/index.html) you can use this piece of code to reset badge value (or change it to any value you want)

`iOSNotificationCenter.ApplicationBadge = 0;`